# Is it possible for a user to only select file save location once?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've been trying to learn how to handle saving normal .txt files in UWP, and have realized that it's quite locked down compared to WPF, especially in the sense of what folders you can access without requesting the user to select a location. I have searched for various ways this might be possible but found no working answer.

---

**Question Description:**

I basically would love to know if this is possible, and preferably a point in the direction where I can learn how exactly to do this.

- Application settings page requires user to select folder where files are saved.
- Application remembers this between launches (unsure if this is possible, but I can't require the user to select the folder on every launch)
- Application saves files to the specified folder.

In my understanding, this should be possible, as the user is the one specifying the location via filepicker, but is it possible to have this work between launches so that the user wont be required to re-select the save folder?

---

I need to figure this out, as I would like my application to support selecting attached network drives, cloud storage folders, etc.

Any help is very much appreciated, and if there are any questions I will answer them to the best of my ability.

Comment: Try this [StorageItemAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207459)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fow this purpose there are two access lists designed: [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457) and [MostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207458). Once the user has picked up the folder with the picker, you add it to such list and receive a token, which you save for future purpose in [LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx):

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyFolder"] = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(pickedFolder);
```

Then later, once you want to access that folder, you can do it like this:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["MyFolder"].ToString());
```

You can't save a *StorageFolder* or a path to it in settings, hence the UWP app needs permissions to access the folder. Using above access lists solves this problem.

Comment: Awesome, would I need to declare the use of this in the manifest? I remember seeing some posts that mention that.

Comment: @DionS.Jensen You don't need to put anything here within manifest - this is the user who grants the permission to folder/files via the picker. Just remember to handle some exceptions hence the above are only sample lines.

Comment: I got the file selection to work, but am having a really weird error with LocalSettings, I've described it in a different post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814611/localsettings-breaking-on-unhandled-xaml-exception?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to save user settings and keep it somewhere so that next time when they launch the application, they can use the same settings.

Please check out this tutorial from Microsoft, which describes how to do exactly that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx